# Advice on how to fix a Progress Bar code in QuickBASIC

Tags: progress-bar, basic, quickbasic

I have a problem that I am hoping someone who is smarter then myself can help me with.

I have this bit of code that I am trying to get to work.

```
SUB ShowProgressBar (FileCount%, NCount%, BarWidth%, BarRow%, BarColum%)

percent = int((Ncount% / FileCount%) * 100)

Locate BarRow%, BarColumn%
Print String$(BarWidth%, Chr$(177))

Locate BarRow%, BarColumn%
Print String$((BarWidth% / 100 * percent), Chr$(178))

Locate BarRow%, (BarColumn% + 12)
Print percent + "%"
```

What I am trying to do is to show in screen 0 a text progress bar.

So first I would print to the screen ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒ (for the background) and then the idea is to fill the progress bar with ▓ until the processing is completed.

What I can not get to work is the actual math of the progress bar.

What I am using this on is a function that reads in a CSV file and creates an ISAM database from it (so it can have anything from 0 to 10,000,000 records or more).

If someone could help me with this it would be most appreciated as I have spent the whole weekend on this and still can not get it to work correctly. I get overflow errors or the progress bar goes over 8-10 lines on screen.

Thank you for any help you can offer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only have 80 columns to work with on screen 0.
If `BarWidth% > 80`, you will see problems.

Adjust things however you want, but this should mostly do what you want:

```
Sub ShowProgressBar (FileCount%, NCount%, BarWidth%, BarRow%, BarColumn%)

' Completed = NCount / FileCount
'   Percent = Int(100      * Completed)
'    Filled = Int(BarWidth * Completed)
'
' Filled/BarWidth represents 100% when FileCount/FileCount files have completed.
' Since Completed represents NCount/FileCount, we can mathematically calculate
'
'    Filled/BarWidth = NCount/FileCount
'             Filled = BarWidth * NCount / FileCount
'
' Then you just apply Fix(), Int(), CInt(), CLng(), etc. to get rid of fractions
' (or use a\b to perform integer division instead of regular division with a/b).
'
percent% = (NCount% * 100) \ FileCount%
filled% = (NCount% * BarWidth%) \ FileCount%

Locate BarRow%, BarColumn%
Print String$(filled%, Chr$(178));
Print String$(BarWidth% - filled%, Chr$(177));

' Assuming `BarWidth%=20`:
'
'     ▓▓▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒   9%
'     ▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒  50%
'     ▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓ 100%
'
' (Of course, this would be printed on BarRow% only, not multiple lines.
' This was just to illustrate what the line below does.)
'
Print Using " ###%"; percent%

End Sub
```

Also, a general tip: try to multiply things before dividing to avoid rounding errors.
This is not always possible, but it is a good idea to take advantage of the opportunity when you can.

Since you mentioned overflow errors, you may want to switch from 16-bit integers with the `%` suffix to 32-bit long integers with the `&` suffix:

- `FileCount%` → `FileCount&`
- `NCount%` → `NCount&`